# Prove or disprove that $A^n=B^n$ implies $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two square matrices $A,B$ such that $A^n=B^n$ for some $n>2$. Is it necessarily true that $A=B$?

It is obvious that if $A^n=B^n=0$ then $A\neq B$ is not necessarily true. What if $A,B\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Scratching my head trying to come up with counter-examples.

Comment: Nope. Consider $-1I$, where $I$ is the identity. $(-1I)^4=I=I^4$.

Comment: Lol I'm such an idiot.

Comment: This isn't even true for real numbers!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^2 =\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score -1):

What is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^2$ ?